# possible to enable ClearType in Office 2013?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013, cleartype

Is it possible to enable ClearType in Office 2013 on Windows 7? Fonts appear not to be rendered quite so well as in 2007, say.

Some older references say that ClearType has been crippled out of 2013, in which case I guess this won't be possible. Is there anything definitive (From MS) stating this?

Comment: There is no way to enable ClearType functionality in Office 2013.  It has to do with changes to a new font rendering API and this new rendering engine not supporting ClearType.  This API was designed for Windows 8.x but back ported to Windows 7

Comment: Still no news in 2023? In Outlook it is very noticeable, as the Inbox mail list uses ClearType and is very crisp and legible, while the reading pane (which is rendered by Word) uses grayscale and even on a 4K display some letters look jerky. I can't believe that Microsoft has not addressed this issue in 10 years!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not really there were many petition trying to get ClearType back.

However you can improve the visuals by:

File > Options > Advanced
Check “Disable hardware graphics acceleration

and

Use Subpixel Positioning to smooth fonts on screen"

Comment: Ok, thanks. Subpixel positioning option appears in the options dialogs of only some apps, Word but not Outlook for example.

Comment: "Use Subpixel Positioning" makes it look worse for me. It's still using grayscale font smoothing, but the option seems to prioritize accurate character spacing over lining up with pixels, so there's more gray half-pixels and it ends up even blurrier. Disabling Subpixel Positioning helps readability a lot.

Comment: I didn't find any improvement using these options in Office 2019, and as mentioned, Outlook lacks some options.  Outlook displays ClearType for the UI but I can't find a way to get the reading pane use subpixel antialiasing.